# Tensorflow - transfer learning implementation (semantic segmentation)

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-segmentation, pre-trained-model

I'm working on implementing a CNN architecture (FCN-8s model, with pretrained VGG16 model) for semantic segmentation on my own data (2 classes, therefore, a binary per-pixel classification)

How I intend to go about this is:

1. Load the pre-trained model with weights
2. Add/remove additional higher layers to convert to FCN
3. Freeze lower layers of the pre-trained model (to not update during the training phase)
4. Train the network on specific dataset

Assuming this is correct, how do I go about freezing the lower layers on my tensorflow model? (I'm looking for specific implementation details) I had a look at the Inception retraining on TensorFlow tutorial, but I'm not quite sure yet.

This is the workflow I have in mind:

1. Run my data through the existing pretrained model, and extract the feature outputs, *without* training it. (how?)
2. Feed these feature outputs into another network containing the higher layers - and go about training it.

Any suggestions would be helpful!

Else, if I'm wrong, how should I be thinking of this?

UPDATE:

I took up [chasep255](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2876799/chasep255)'s suggestion below, and tried to use [tf.stop_gradient](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/train.html#stop_gradient) so as to "freeze" the lower layers in my model. Clearly, there is something wrong with my implementation. Possible alternatives/suggestions?

The model is built based on the FCN (for semantic segmentation) paper. I extract `logits` from the model architecture, i.e., my features, that I initially feed directly into a `loss` function to minimize it with a softmax classifier. (per-pixel classification) `deconv_1` is my logits tensor, of shape `[batch, h, w, num_classes] = [1, 750, 750, 2]` Implementation:

```
logits = vgg_fcn.deconv_1

stopper = tf.stop_gradient(logits, 'stop_gradients')

loss = train_func.loss(stopper, labels_placeholder, 2)

with tf.name_scope('Optimizer'):
    train_op = train_func.training(loss, FLAGS.learning_rate)

    with tf.name_scope('Accuracy'):
        eval_correct = train_func.accuracy_eval(logits, labels_placeholder)
        accuracy_summary = tf.scalar_summary('Accuracy', eval_correct)
```

I then run these Graph operations as below:

```
_, acc, loss_value = sess.run([train_op,eval_correct, loss], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

When I run the training cycle thus, there is no optimization of the loss value, most definitely because of how I've introduced the `tf.stop_gradient` Op.

For more details, my loss function below:

```
def loss(logits, labels, num_classes):

    logits = tf.reshape(logits, [-1, num_classes])
    #epsilon = tf.constant(value=1e-4)
    #logits = logits + epsilon

    labels = tf.to_int64(tf.reshape(labels, [-1]))
    print ('shape of logits: %s' % str(logits.get_shape()))
    print ('shape of labels: %s' % str(labels.get_shape()))

    cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels, name='Cross_Entropy')
    cross_entropy_mean = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy, name='xentropy_mean')
    tf.add_to_collection('losses', cross_entropy_mean)

    loss = tf.add_n(tf.get_collection('losses'), name='total_loss')
    return loss
```

Comment: Hi murushiv, with respect to your code of logits = vgg_fcn.deconv_1, are you using the fcn implementation of MarvinTeichmann? I read his code, and did not find deconv_1. would you like to share more information?

Comment: @user288609 It is a slightly modified version. deconv_1 is the same as  one of the upscore methods. (or modules?) But I realized there was an error here, in that I should be tapping in before the upscore, use that as logits and train even the upsampling layer, if that makes sense.

Comment: Hi murushiv, in their fcn implementation, there is "pred" layer before the "self.upscore2", do you mean using logits(pred) directly in the loss function? By the way, you said there was an error. Can you elaborate more? I am trying to understand their implementation. Thank you for the help.

Comment: exactly. But I'm not sure if that's right. in this implementation above, I called upon vgg_fcn.deconv_1 (or vgg_fcn.score_fr) instead of vgg_fcn.pred.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just pass the output of the pretrained model into sess.run(pretrained_output, ...) and capture the output of the pretrained model.  After you save the output you could then feed it into your model.  In this case the optimizer would not be able to propagate the gradients to the pretrained model.

You could also attach the pre trained model to you model normally and then pass the pretrained output through tf.stop_graidents() which would prevent the optimizer from propagating the gradients back into the pretrained model.

Finally, you could just go through all the variables in the pretrained model and remove them from the list of trainable variables.

Comment: tf.stop_gradients() seems to be exactly what I needed, but couldn't articulate well enough to find it. I ended up doing what you suggest here in the first method, and I've got the pipeline ready. Might consider replacing it with stop_gradients() if I need to tweak the pre-trained parameters as well. Seems to be a much cleaner solution.

Comment: Updated my question with some code, on my implementation of the tf.stop_gradients() op. Could you take a quick look and see why/where I'm going wrong with it?

Comment: You are passing the stop gradients directly into the loss function so there is nothing to optimize.

Comment: got it! suggestion on where I should be passing it instead? Somewhere between the lower layers?